# Arduino Uno outputs 8V when pin is set to HIGH

Tags: arduino-uno

I am doing the following in setup:

```
 pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
```

When I check with the multimeter, I get an output voltage of 8V rather than 5V. What may be the problem and how do I troubleshoot it?.

Comment: You have a badly calibrated multimeter? Try it on something where you know what the voltage should be, such as a 9V battery and see what it reads.

Comment: @Majenko : You were right. My DMM battery is low, hence its showing some wrong values :). I will replace it with a new one.

Comment: Is the code as shown what you actually have?  `pinMode(13, HIGH);` is invalid.  Perhaps you meant `digitalWrite(13, HIGH);`

Comment: You need to show more code. Your posted code doesn't do a digitalWrite, and even if it did, if it wrote HIGH and then LOW in quick succession you may get an unexpected reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a badly calibrated multimeter.

Try it on something where you know what the voltage should be, such as a 9V battery and see what it reads.

Comment: Yes, the meter should be suspect, but, I'd expect a "9v" battery to read anything from zero to close to ten volts with a calibrated meter, depending on chemistry, cell count, and condition.  Probably better to measure the circuit's supply and describe its source.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, but if it is the multimeter at fault then I'd expect the 9V battery to read something like 12V or more to be inline with what the Arduino is measuring at. That can't happen with a 9V battery no matter how much charge it has left.